# How I can create function prev_id?

Tags: php

How I can create function prev_id for example code using mysqli_fetch_array:

```
$idprev = prev_id();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM site WHERE id='$idprev' ";
```

This function not exist in php.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function prev_id()

Comment: ??? Well what do you want the function to do? Are you trying to get the last ID which was inserted into your database? If so, then whatever database library you're using (e.g. mysqli, PDO etc) will already have a function for that, so check the documentation.

Comment: P.S. _In general_, the way to create a function is to write `function prev_id() { }`, but I suspect that's not actually what your question is (despite the way it's worded).

Comment: The PHP manual has a page on [User-​defined functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)

Comment: Are you looking for something connected to the `prev()` function?

Comment: generally I want create own previous_post etc, I want one file for all page

Comment: You'll need to be much more specific that that. See [ask]. Also you haven't answered any of the queries posed to you. If you want useful help you need to make some effort as well.

Answer (score 1):

you need to define function prev_id() first  before using it.

```
<?php
    function prev_id()
    {
         // your code lines
         return $yourvariable;
    }
?>
```